# Java program to display numbers between two ranges using command line arguement

Tags: java, class, javac

//Program to display prime numbers between 2 range using command line argument

```
class prime
{
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    if(args.length!=2)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter both starting & ending limit, only 2");
        System.exit(0);
    }
int num=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num1=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int count;
if (count<=1)
{
    System.out.println("Prime numbers starts from 2");
    System.exit(0);
}
for(int i=num; i<num1; i++)
{
    count=0;
    for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
    {
        count++;
        break;
    }
if(count==0)
System.out.print(i);
}
}
}
```

This is the error:

```
javac prime.java
prime.java:15: error: variable count might not have been initialized
if (count<=1)
```

But I have initialised it already.
Any help?
I am new to SO

Comment: Not that it solves this problem, but are you sure that this is right `int num=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num1=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`?

Answer (score 0):

you need initialize `count` variable, something like

```
int count = 0;
```

your error message clearly says

> : error: variable **count** might not have been initialized

Comment: I have initialised now:
        `int count=0;`
Now the error is:
        `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin> java prime 2 10`
        `Prime numbers starts from 2`

Comment: so what is the issue now?